# squid access control list for source machines

Tags: networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I am setting up a Squid proxy for home network that is on Wi-fi. I have given static IPs to my desktop machine and laptop at home and I want only these machines to be able to connect to internet. The squid acl I have is

```
acl home_ws src 192.168.4.1
acl home_laptop src 192.168.4.2
acl google     dstdomain google.co.in
http_access allow home_ws
http_access allow home_laptop
http_access allow google
http_port 8080
```

But, when I try to connect with the squid proxy ip from my laptop, it doesn't work. The same however works fine on the desktop. I am using `curl` for this purpose. The error is `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`. This is how I am using the `curl` command.

```
curl --proxy 192.168.4.1:8080 www.google.co.in
```

The ping to my desktop machine(`192.168.4.1`) is working fine. Am I missing something with `squid.conf`?